# Can we find dipole moment of water from a familiar property?

Tags: water, dipole

There are many videos on Youtube showing deflection of a stream of water by a charged rod. My question is whether we can do a rough calculation of the dipole moment of water molecules using this deflection.

My reasoning is: we can approximate the water stream as a short cylinder which, as it falls, travels a measured distance horizontally. This gives us a horizontal force which we can relate to the charge and induced charge on the surface of the rod and cylinder of water.

I am omitting my calculations, which did not come close. I assumed a cylindrical stream of 3mm diameter, 10 mm long, 23 cm above a sink, displaced about 3 cm by a negatively charged rod placed 4 mm from the stream (near the top). I have some confidence in the force measured, little beyond that.

There are a lot of geometrical simplifications to be made but I may be missing subtleties about the way charge behaves on the surface of water and how to relate that to the dipole moment. If anyone has a plausible calculation (or just an outline, highlighting sources of potential error), or reasons why this cannot be done, either one would probably help my intuition.

Comment: Cool question! You might find [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed073p887#) useful.

Comment: @Paul: This was an interesting article, thanks. I used a cylindrical stream so my  volume was larger but the deflection force was also comparable to the force of gravity.

Comment: The dielectric constant is fairly easy to measure accurately, though it might require a simple AC current meter and source.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Yes, don't see a way around that. Unless someone has a better idea I think this must be taken as measured/known.